# Why am I having a problem accessing $el in my view in BackboneJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, handlebars.js

I'm trying to utilize the append method through the el in the BackBoneJS view. I'm using Handlebars.

When I run my code, I get this in the console:

```
main.js:14 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'html')
    at d.render (main.js:14:14)
    at main.js:23:43
```

Here also are the console logs and responses to the following:

```
videoViewer.el
  <div>​</div>​

videoViewer.$el
  undefined
```

Here is my JavaScript:

```
const VideoViewerModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    video: '',
    title: '',
    description: ''
  }
})


const VideoViewerViewer = Backbone.View.extend({
  template: Handlebars.compile($('#video-view-template').html()),

  render: function () {
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.attributes))
  },

});

const videoModel = new VideoViewerModel();

const videoViewer = new VideoViewerViewer({ model: videoModel });

$('.viewer-container').append(videoViewer.render().el);
```

Can anyone catch why my $el seems non-existent?

Comment: It looks to me that you need to add `return this` to the end of your `render` function body. See: https://backbonejs.org/#View-render

Comment: @76484 Thank you. Follow up question to that: I noticed that `return this` is in the source code for `render`. Why do we put it in our code if it is already in the source code?

Comment: You are overwriting the `.render` method in your `VideoViewerViewer` object. Therefore, it doesn't matter what is in the source code because you are overwriting the source code (for `.render`).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I had some other problems that were more fundamental. I hadn't installed underscore (I falsely assumed that it was part of the BackBone package).

I also had the dependencies improperly linked in the `<head>`.

It needed to look like this:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Backbone YouTube</title>
    <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/backbone/backbone-min.js"></script>
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="./node_modules/handlebars/dist/handlebars.min.js"
    ></script>
  </head>
```